# Add a new sheet to a existing workbook in python

Tags: python, excel

I have browsed almost all the previous threads, but still cannot get this working.I am trying to add a new sheet to an existing workbook. My code works,but it keeps on adding a lot more (so many of them actually) sheets. I can't figure out the solution.Below is my code

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('template.xlsx')
from xlutils.copy import copy as xl_copy
wb = xl_copy(wb2)
wb.create_sheet('sid1')
wb.save('template.xlsx')
```

Comment: I'm surprised you don't get a different kind of error. `xlutils` wasn't designed to work with `openpyxl`. In particular, the line `wb = xl_copy(wb2)` seems destined for failure. Even if it somehow doesn't produce any errors, it's completely unnecessary, as `openpyxl` doesn't need (and really can't use) what `xlutils.copy` provides.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

If you want to add a sheet to an existing spreadsheet, just go ahead and add the new sheet to the file instead of copying your `load` object and trying to add the new sheet to it.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
wb2 = load_workbook('template.xlsx')
wb2.create_sheet('sid1')
wb2.save('template.xlsx')
```

Comment: @fsociety, i tried it locally and it worked just fine. Are you sure this is all the code you are running and not just a spinet of a bigger code. I think there might be a loop somewhere

Comment: apologies, you are right...i just figured out the mess i have been making :)

Comment: @fsociety yeah glad that helped

Comment: This works well, it also sets that new sheet as the current active sheet.

Comment: add at end .... wb2..close()