# python segment data from column

Tags: python, excel, segment

I need to open an excel work sheet, and create different excel sheets segmenting from data.

- Ancienneté      Site    1 - Mon territoire
  -Direction Générale 2   paris   2
  -COMEX              0   paris   2
  -Direction Générale 12  paris   2
  -Développement      21  ollioules 2

For example, I need to create different sheets for each city, paris, ollioules ( i have different cities) and get all of the informations in that row.
Until now I have:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*

import openpyxl as px
workbook = px.load_workbook('digital_trust.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_names()

for worksheet in worksheet:
    worksheet = workbook.get_sheet_by_name()

    for row in worksheet.iter_rows(row_offset=2):
        ville = row[3].value        
        print ville
```

Comment: fist of all you have a problem if you want to use for worksheet in worksheet... change the following "worksheet = " to "worksheets = " and "for worksheet in worksheet" to "for worksheet in worksheets" because you overwrite the first variable with the worksheet name of the first worksheet.

Comment: Do you want to create new sheets or do you want to rename the existing ones according to the name of the city?

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40385840/5621032) you only need to add workbook.create_sheet(ville).

Comment: But i want to get all the information by city name

Comment: What do you want? new sheets that are named as the cities? or do you want to change the name of the sheet you get the name of the city out?

Comment: I want a new sheet for each city name, and the information for that row
For example:
Paris ...
sheet 2 for another city..

Comment: Read [Simple usage wb.create_sheet](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/usage.html)