# How to create a new sheet inside a quip spreadsheet document via quip Python API?

Tags: python, github, quip

I had a question and was wondering if there is any possible solution to achieve this via quip python automation API.

I have some data which I am getting from a source and then creating a new quip spreadsheet every time to insert data into it. I don't want to create a new quip spreadsheet every-time, I want it to use the same spreadsheet and create a new sheet in that (similar to how we can create a new sheet in excel) and insert data into that. Is this possible using Python quip automation?

I looked into github Python API doc but couldn't find any method that would create a new sheet in the same spreadsheet.
There is a method that creates a spreadsheet itself but not the sheet inside the spreadsheet.

I looked into github Python API doc but couldn't find any method that would create a new sheet in the same spreadsheet.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a new sheet to a existing workbook in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385689/add-a-new-sheet-to-a-existing-workbook-in-python)

Comment: This is adding a sheet to the .xlsx file. I need to add it to a QUIP workbook actually.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to add a new tab to an existing spreadsheet by just creating a new html table and passing that as "content" to the edit_document command, referencing the thread_id of the original table.

```
html_content = """\
<table title='test_tab_2'>
  <tr>
    <th>name</th>
    <th>id</th> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
 </tr>
</table>
"""
```