How to replace an Excel sheet in a complex notebook with Python
I’m stuck working with an Excel workbook that is filled with multiple pivot tables and figures. Updating the workbook requires writing over the raw data split across six Excel sheets. I want to automate the update process by having Python replace the raw data sheets.
The only suggestion I've found is to use openpyxl. For example:
with pd.ExcelWriter('filename.xlsx', engine='openpyxl', mode='a') as writer:
    df1.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='sheet1',index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer,sheet_name='sheet2',index=False)

Unfortunately, I think the complexity of the original Excel workbook is an issue, as I have to give up after waiting for more than 10 minutes. I've only had success with this method when I've replaced the existing data sheets with extremely simple data tables.
Is there any way to replace worksheets in, or just add worksheets to, an existing workbook with a ton of complexity? E.g., a method that lets one copy worksheets into a workbook without processing the pre-existing contents of the workbook?

Seems like you should separate the data into a completely separate workbook: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-workbook-links-c98d1803-dd75-4668-ac6a-d7cca2a9b95f

about adding worksheets to an existing workbook: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40385689/add-a-new-sheet-to-a-existing-workbook-in-python

I’m not entirely sure of your full workflow, so it’s a bit tricky to suggest the perfect solution. That said, based on my experience, the capabilities of Python libraries for Excel operations can be quite limited. Are you trying to do things like merging files, merging sheets, or adding sheets? If so, there’s an Excel automation tool called SheetFlash that might be worth looking into.
It works a bit like a Python notebook—you can set up each action as a card, and then simply press the “Run All” button to execute all the actions in one go. It’s an add-in that could potentially solve your issue.
